# Which databound control should I use for nested databound controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I want to render something like this (with ASP.Net Controls in the codebehind):

```
<ul>
<li class="first"><h1>This is a caption</h1></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="first"><h1>This is a another caption</h1></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo6</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo7</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" target="_self">Foo11</a></li>
</ul>

...
```

The amount of li elements that will be rendered into each ul is determined at runtime. Each link in a li belongs to into a specific ul (the one containing a specific caption. Imagine this as a kind of a treeview with nodes and subnodes)

During the bind Event I need access to an ASP:HyperLink that will be rendered into the a-element.

Which databound ASP.Net control should I pick for this?
Looks like a repeater in a repeater, which should make the databinding process ugly.

I'm thinking about creating this HTML-Output with StringWriters myself.

Which way should I prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested repeaters will work fine. I have used them before in this kind of scenario and they worked a treat.

I don't know why you think the databinding will be bad - simply make sure to use the right binding expressions.

Comment: I think I'm somehow stuck at thinking this through right now: I have  List<MyCustomObject> where each MyCustomObject contains another List<MyCustomObject>. How would the code for a nested repeater with custom objects look like? Or doesn't it work for my purpose?

Comment: @citronas - it should. You simply set the `DataMember` of the nested repeater to the property that holds the inner list (you can do this in markup).

Comment: Unfortunetly I wasn't able to (because of the way the databinding in the DLL, I was forced to use, works) nested repeaters. If I come across this situation again I'll remember your post and use the DataMember property